# Issue with transition for background property

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I try to make ring progress bar, it's almost done, but I can't make proper animation. I add transition for background, but animation doesn't works.
This is my css style for progress ring.

```
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
      background: conic-gradient(red <change this value with js>%, 0, #ECEFF1 <change this value with js>%);

    transition: background .3s linear;
    border-radius: 50%;
```

Comment: you cannot animate conic-gradient this way

Comment: oh :(  okay, I'll try another way.

Comment: since you are changing the value with JS, change them slowly to simulate the animation.

Comment: It'll leads to a lot of operations to update progress ring(I just tried it) and I would like animation ease in effect.

Comment: share your full code with this method so we can see the result and we can probably give you a different idea to solve your issue without conic-gradient (which is still not supported everywhere by the way)